# Phase velocity expression

Tags: resonance, theory, phase, speed

We have a \$\beta l\$ expression which is represented as phase velocity.
I know \$\omega_o=2\pi f\$.

What is the exact expression for phase velocity used in here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

βl presents how much phase lag a line ( which has length =l) causes to a single sinusoidal wave which propagates along the line. β is called propagation coefficient. In some books it's called phase constant. It's NOT the same as the phase velocity.

It's not at all a constant, because it depends on frequency.

The dimensional unit of β is radians per meter. Speaking exactly it's written as 1/m because radians actually have no dimension. Saying "radians" is only a habit.

It can be said as well by using the TEM wave propagation velocity v (which is also the phase velocity of pure TEM waveform and has SI-unit = meters per a second):

β = 2πf/v

The velocity v can be calculated from the primary line properties such as inductance and capacitance per unit length, as you hopefully have heard or seen.